# Generic collection in .net that allow birectional iteration

Tags: collections, ienumerable, icollection

I was looking at the .net generic collections like ICollection, IEnumerable to see any that can support bidirectional navigation with methods like MoveNext, MovePrevious. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that ICollectionView supports MoveNext, MovePrevious.